# how do I Import from .txt or convert existing list as variable not string

Tags: python, list, variables, import

Basically, I want to create a list of variables so that I can define them all as something like

```
mylist = [] 
with open("import.txt") as bList:
    var = line.split()
    mylist.append(var)

for variable in mylist:
    variable = class(variable)
```

I know the `for` statement isnt correct, but that is the general desired result.

I dont want a dictionary, because I want to be able to call `variable.classattribute` for prints and such.

during testing, I used the manually entered `variable = class('variable')` with success, but I have a list of 200-300 items on a list thats changing / being generated through the `import.txt` and automated the process has been a task for my relatively new skillset.

Comment: stop calling your lists "list"

Comment: I just used generic names to show the general code layout I am working with. None of those names are what im actually using.

Comment: Any code that you post here might be run by someone trying to reproduce your problem.  If you call variables the same as a built-in class (`list`) it could have side-effects that might mis-lead, so please don't do that.

Comment: Use a dictionary, you can store the "variable" name as the text key and the object as the value, that lets you use:  `mydict['variable'].classattribute`.